# Build JSON array from JSON items

Tags: javascript, ruby, json

The client browser sends JSON data to the server, the server saves this raw JSON information (String) in a `history` array (Ruby array).
When another user asks for this history, the server sends the information as a JSON array.

I can't simply use `history.to_json` here since this will convert the already JSON objects inside the array to JSON objects.

An alternative would be parsing the JSON data and inserting that data as a Ruby object to the array, and then converting the entire array to JSON when it is asked, but this seems like a waste of parsing the received data just so I can later on convert it again to JSON.

I was looking for a JSON builder for Ruby but couldn't find one. Anyone got a hint?

Answer (score 0):

If you're passing the JSON string back to a client, could you not just pass the string back and parse it in javascript using `JSON.parse` method?